# My Dell Vostro 3300 speakers are not working

Tags: windows-7

I am using a Dell Vostro 3300. I connected my laptop to a projector, and after removing the cable from the projector my speakers are not working. If I plug in headphones it's working, but without headphones there is no sound. I am using Win7 Professional, i5 processor, 4Gb Ram, 320Gb HD.

Answer (score 0):

try following

1. Try to **reinstall your sound driver** this should most probably solve the problem
2. Go to control panel and **check sound option** it will show you speaker check its properties if its working correctly.
3. This might sound nonsense but still check if **volume is set to very low** on your speaker or if there is some power cable attached to speaker is it on. pins connected to correct port.
4. Check in **sound mixer** if anything is set to mute(Click on sound icon on taskbar you will get link to mixer)